# Seeing or filtering using indexed columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Using Python's pandas library, I imported a csv and set multiple columns as my index. Unexpectedly, the indexed columns are no longer present when I display the dataframe and I can't use the index columns as filter option. Google tells me that when I set my index, I should set 'drop' to False. This has me wondering if I am mistaken in thinking of pandas indexes as being similar to SQL indexes.

Say my data looks like this (simplified dummy example for stock market prices):

```
date, exchange, symbol, low, high, open, close, last
```

`date`, `exchange`, and `symbol` are sufficient to uniquely identify a row.

First, what is the point of creating an index? Does it speed up lookups or does it add some semantic information useful for things like stack/unstack/pivot/groupby? Does it reduce memory usage?

Why are date, exchange, and symbol moved out of dataframe (and moved to index series?)? Doesn't it make sense to leave them in the dataframe where I can filter on them as df[df.symbol=='MSFT']? I guess 'drop' solves this, but the fact that this isn't default means I'm misunderstanding something here.

Comment: Have a look at the [indexing docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) if you haven't yet. For your `df[df.symbol=='MSFT']` example it would be `df.loc['MSFT']`

Comment: @TomAugspurger the docs you linked to aren't clear for multi-indexes, they reference a text based (experimental) query language. What is the idiomatic way of asking for data where symbol=='MSFT AND exchange=='BATS'?

Comment: `df.loc[('MSFT', 'BATS')]`, assuming that's the order of your MultiIndex. Give it some time to learn and you'll find it's pretty intuitive.
But I think the docs answer your original question of "what is the point of creating an index?" 1. Identifies data, 2. alignment 3. getting and setting

Comment: I was able to get the data I wanted by using the following expression: data.loc[201406,'BATS','MSFT',:,:][['low','high']]. Reading the docs in a more systematic manner helped :). Still not completely intuitive to me but I have high hopes.

Answer (score 1):

Indices are used to select and align rows of a data frame. The way I think of them is as labels for the dataframe rows, with the rows containing the data values. They enable you to use a dataframe to store higher dimensional data in a convenient way. I found them a little tricky starting out, but when you are aligning data sets they really shine.

You need the xs method to access the inner levels of a multiindex. To do what you want try the following.

```
df.xs(('BATS', 'MSFT'), level=(1, 2))
```

Alternatively you can refrain from setting an index and use boolean indexing to select multiple criteria.

```
bats_mask = df.exchange == 'BATS'
msft_mask = df.symbol == 'MSFT'
df[bats_mask & msft_mask]
```